# Reversing a string using stack is not working for me

Tags: c, stack

So i was writting a code to reverse a string using stack but the output always

seem wrong,anyone can tell whats the problem?!

when i write a string like hello the output should be "olleh" but its "ollo"
any idea why that happening

**the code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 101

void push(char );
void pop();
char Top();
void print();



char A[MAX_SIZE];
int top=-1;

void rev(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        push(A[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        A[i]=Top();
        pop();
    }

}

void main()
{

    printf("enter a string: ");
    gets(A);
    rev(strlen(A));
    printf("output= %s",A);
}

void push(char a)
{
    if (top == MAX_SIZE -1){
        printf("Error: stack overflow\n");
        return;
    }
    A[++top] = a;
}

void pop()
{
    if(top==-1){
      printf("Error: stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    top--;
}

char Top()
{
    return A[top];
}

void print()
{
    int i;
    printf("Stack: ");
    for(i=0;i<=top;i++){
        printf("%d ",A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

this is the output in screenshoot

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dXE.jpg)

Comment: I recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, never *ever* use `gets`. It's a dangerous function and has therefore been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Lastly about your problem: You use `A` *both* for the string *and* the stack. That's not going to work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there!

First of all, don't use the *dangerous* gets(), use fgets instead

```
    fgets(A,MAX_SIZE,stdin);
```

then the reverse function is almost fine, but you are overwriting the same string, re-using (from half the string) chars you just copied from the tail (of stack / string).

Make the stack another array

```
char A[MAX_SIZE]; // input string
char S[MAX_SIZE]; // stack
```

in push / pop / top use only the stack, replace the `A[...]` with `S[...]`

Note: would be more elegant to use `pop()` without `Top()`, having `pop` return the char from the 'top' of the stack

```
char pop();
```

in `rev()`

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    A[i] = pop();
}
```

`pop()` being

```
char pop() {
    if(top==-1){
       printf("Error: stack is empty\n");
       return 0;
    }
    return S[top--];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the push function is added to the same variable that the has the user input

Please add another variable then ‘char A[]’ for the stack

Further explanations: if you started reversing “hello” the push function would replace “h” with “o” and that’s what you see

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in that your pop function accesses the stack directly, the same one you are reading from
so you are overwriting prematurely the contents

Example

```
ABC
```

push A, push B, push C, top is now 2

```
C  A[2]
B  A[1]
A  A[0]
```

so then you loop from 0 to 2

```
A[0] = Top() ;
```

now you overwrite A[0] 'A' with A[2] 'C' but you fail to store the previous value 'A'

the stack contents look like

```
A[2] C
A[1] B
A[0] C
```

Simplest is just to have a second array

```
char B[MAX_SIZE]
```

To traverse your stack do something like this

```
for (i = top, j = 0; i >= 0; --i)
{
  B[j++] = A[i];
}
```

(alt do a Pop function that returns the top value)

If you need to use only one array (for whatever academic reason)
swap the values

```
for (i = top, j = 0; i >= 0; --i)
{
  if (i != j)
  {
    tmp = A[j];
    A[j] = A[i];
    A[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```